# How to get value of an input (checkbox input) in auto generated forms that displayed as table rows?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, sql-update

I generate table from database, assign each cell as checkbox value, group each row as form and display them all as table refer to [this].[1](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) How I can get particular cell value when i click on the button since each form (row) have a same id. I want to pass the value as query parameter to update the database table. I have searched for similar technique and still not find the solution.

This code is within a cursor fetching loop:

```html
    <form class="tr" id="barisn" method="post" action="">
     <span class="td"><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="<?php $data[0]?>"/><label for="id"><?php echo $data[0]?></label></span>
     <span class="td"><input type="checkbox" name="name" value="<?php $data[1]?>" /><label for="name"><?php echo $data[1]?></label></span>
     <span class="td"><input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="<?php $gender?>" /><label for="gender"><?php echo $gender?></label></span>
     <span class="td"><input type="checkbox" name="sender" value="<?php $data[8]?>" /><label for="sender"><?php echo $data[8]?></label></span>
     <span class="td"><input type="checkbox" name="date" value="<?php $data[5]?>" /><label for="date"><?php echo $data[5]?></label></span>
     <span class="td"><input type="checkbox" name="time" value="<?php $data[6]?>" /><label for="time"><?php echo $data[6]?></label></span>
     <span class="td"><input type="checkbox" name="state" value="<?php $state?>" /><label for="state"><?php echo $state?></label></span>
     <div class="td">
      <button class="btn-rawuh" type="submit" form="barisn" value="Rawuh">Rawuh</button>
      <button class="btn-tundha" type="submit" form="barisn" value="Tundha">Tundha</button>
      <button class="btn-mlebet" type="submit" form="barisn" value="Mlebet">Mlebet</button>
     </div>
    </form>
```

[image: The point is I still can not find a method to indexing row as user may click a button in it. Table result:]

Answer (score 0):

You have to put anchor tag instead of button like this

```
<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $here_ur_dynamic_PK_of_that_row[index_value] ?>">Edit</a>
```

when you click on edit button then page will redirect to edit.php(you have to create new php file) then get the id from url :

```
echo $_GET method
```

then u will get the details of that particular row using id (using query).

Comment: Thank Rahul for your enlightenme,  so now... i got confused what index parameter should i put in that. the need is get value of index 0 and index 7. for instance when i click anchor "Rawuh" in row 4, the action should be get value of index 0 of row 4 (index 3 in logic)  ("6") and value of anchor's text ("Rawuh"). what i still confused is how I get index 3?

Comment: Refer this code: $query_c_s_c=  mysql_query("select id,country_name,state_name,city_name from stud_rec");
  while($row_c_s_c=  mysql_fetch_array($query_c_s_c))
  {
       
      echo "<td>".$row_c_s_c['country_name']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row_c_s_c['state_name']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row_c_s_c['city_name']."</td>";
      echo "<td><a href=edit.php?id=".$row_c_s_c['id']."><b>Edit Record</b></a>.</td>";
      echo "<td><a href=delete.php?id=".$row_c_s_c['id']."><b>Delete Record</b></a>.</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      
  }